# $cmd output in to a file

Tags: perl, cmd

I have this below code:

```
$cmd = system ("p4 change -o 3456789");
```

I want to print the output -description of the change list - into a file.

```
$cmd = system ("p4 change -o 3456789 > output_cl.txt");
```

will write the output in to `output_cl.txt` file.

But, is there anyway to get the output through `$cmd`?

```
open(OUTPUT, ">$output_cl.txt") || die "Wrong Filename";
print OUTPUT ("$cmd");
```

will write 0 or 1 to the file. How to get the output from `$cmd`?

Comment: Your question is confusing.  Do you want the output of the original command `p4 change -o 3456789` or do you want something else?  If you want the output of the original command, don't use `system`.  Instead, use backticks.

Answer (score 2):

To store the output of your `p4` command into  an array, use [qx](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/qx.html):

```
my @lines = qx(p4 change -o 3456789);
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to grabbing the entire output of a command with [`qx//` or backticks](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators), you can get a handle on a command's output. For example

```
open my $p4, "-|", "p4 change -o 3456789"
  or die "$0: open p4: $!";
```

Now you can read `$p4` a line at a time and possibly manipulate it as in

```
while (<$p4>) {
  print OUTPUT lc($_);  # no shouting please!
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always use the following process to dump output straight to a file.

1) *dup* the system `STDOUT` file descriptor, 2) `open STDOUT`, 3) system, 4) copy the IO slot back into `STDOUT`:

```
open( my $save_stdout, '>&1' );              # dup the file
open( STDOUT, '>', '/path/to/output/glop' ); # open STDOUT
system( qw<cmd.exe /C dir> );                # system (on windows)
*::STDOUT = $save_stdout;                    # overwrite STDOUT{IO}
print "Back to STDOUT!";                     # this should show up in output
```

But `qx//` is probably what you're looking for.

reference: [`perlopentut`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlopentut.html)

---

Of course this could be generalized:

```
sub command_to_file { 
    my $arg = shift;
    my ( $command, $rdir, $file ) = $arg =~ /(.*?)\s*(>{1,2})\s*([^>]+)$/;
    unless ( $command ) { 
       $command = $arg;
       $arg     = shift;
       ( $rdir, $file ) = $arg =~ /\s*(>{1,2})\s*([^>]*)$/;
       if ( !$rdir ) { 
           ( $rdir, $file ) = ( '>', $arg );
       }
       elsif ( !$file ) { 
           $file = shift;
       }
    }
    open( my $save_stdout, '>&1' );
    open( STDOUT, $rdir, $file );
    print $command, "\n\n";
    system( split /\s+/, $command );
    *::STDOUT = $save_stdout;
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you find it confusing remembering what you need to run in order to get a command's return value, vs. its output, or how to handle different return codes, or forget to right-shift the resulting code, you need [IPC::System::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IPC::System::Simple), which makes all this, well, simple:

```
use IPC::System::Simple qw(system systemx capture capturex);

my $change_num = 3456789;
my $output = capture(qw(p4 change -o), $change_num);
```